# Symfony 2 problems with subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I think i have a problem with htaccess.

I have a subdomain which redirects to a folder such as `subdomain.domain.com --> home/subdomain`

The problem is that if i write `subdomain.domain.com` is not redirected to app.php, if i write subdomain.domain.com/app.php it works.

On the other side if i write `domain.com/subdomain/web` (supossing that this is the route to the app) there is no need to write app.php.

So it works with both:
`domain.com/subdomain/web/ and domain.com/subdomain/web/app.php`

I have the following htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have no idea about htaccess

PS: i don't know if the problem has been understood, i want to direcly acces subdomain.domain.com/app.php when i write subdomain/domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/%1$1
```

check this:  http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-apache-mod_rewrite-methods/
and search for "sub-domain"

Comment: doesn´t work, i will look at the provided link, thanks any way

Comment: i don't know if the problem has been understood, i want to direcly acces subdomain.domain.com/app.php when i write subdomain/domain.com

Comment: i am learning about it, and i think you were right, but i doen't work yet, if i find the solution i will post it, i found an interesting link that could help somebody: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: my problem is solved, the solution? magical, i do not knwo what happened but i suddenly works, I suposse that I didn't have the proper .htacces in the remote server, i uploaded the files again and it worked with the initial  .htaccess. Any way, this has helped me learning about this file. Hope the provided links will help more people. Thanks

Comment: Nice :D That's the important :D